# jQuery: When entering text in input field, doesn't enable the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hhimanshu/9kKXX/).

***jQuery***

```
$(function() {
    //var input = $('form :input[type="text"]')
    $('form :input[type="text"]').live('keyup', function() {
        $('form .create-playlist-button')
            .attr('disabled', $('form :input[type="text"]').val().length == 0);
    });
});
```

**Needed**

- When I start entering the data in the textbox, create should be enabled.
- When I remove all text from the textbox, create should be disabled.

I am very new to jQuery and this thing is not working for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('form :input[type="text"]').live('keyup', function() {
      var val = $.trim(this.value); // this.value is faster than $(this).val()
      $('form .create-playlist-button').prop('disabled', val.length == 0);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9kKXX/3/)**

Here, I used **[`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop)** instead of **[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr)**, according to jQuery doc `.prop()` should be use. I also used **[`.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)** for removing  the whitespace from the beginning and end of value.

---

#### About your code

In your code you used `$('form :input[type="text"]')` two times, one for bind event and one to getting the value of text field. But that is not necessary, because within `keyup` event handler function `this` will refers to that `input` element on which `keyup` event binded.

If you sometime need to use any selector multiple times for any purpose it will be better to cache that in a variable and reuse that variable. Just for example:

```
var input = $('form :input[type="text"]');
input.on('click', function() {
      alert( this.value );
      input.addClass('something');
});
```

---

If would be better if you use **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)** instead of `.live()` for delegate event handler, because `.live()` has been deprecated.

You can use `.on()` like following:

```
$('form').on('keyup', ':input[type="text"]', function() {
   var val = $.trim(this.value);
   $('form .create-playlist-button').prop('disabled', val.length == 0);
});
```

---

#### Note

Syntax of `.on()` for delegate event handling is like:

```
$(staticContainer).on( eventName, target, handlerFunction )
```

Here, `staticContainer` point to an element which belong to DOM at page load, i.e which is not dynamic and also container of `target` on which you want to bind your event.

---

#### Just for some more go here

- [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)
- http://forum.jquery.com/topic/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-attr-and-jquery-prop

Comment: Huge thanks for the detailed answer, definitely helped me in understanding jQuery a little better, I appreciate your time @thecodeparadox

Answer (score 4):

Updated:

```
$(function(){
    //var input = $('form :input[type="text"]')
    $('form :input[type="text"]').live('keyup',function(){   
            $(this).closest('form').find('.create-playlist-button').prop('disabled',$(this).val().length==0);
     });
});
```

In the "keyup" handler, you use `this` (or `$(this)` to use it via jQuery) to get at the text field that's actually involved. I also changed the code to ensure you'll find the correct "companion" button. It looks up the chain of parent elements to find the enclosing `<form>`, then finds the button inside that form.

The way you're assigning the event handlers is deprecated. It should be:

```
    $('form').on('keyup', ':input[type="text"]', function(){ ...
```

Also if you checked for "keypress" instead of "keyup" you'd fix the bug wherein the button doesn't work until the second character.

*edit* — oh and one more thing: you should usually use `.prop()` to update attributes, not `.attr()`.  It's a confusing thing about the newer jQuery API, but the times you need to use `.attr` are kind-of rare. Unfortunately, there's a ton of old instructional material out there that was written back before jQuery 1.6 was released.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the .change() method !

And inside it juste do a test:

```
if ($(this).val().length > 0)
...
else
...
```

Answer (score 0):

here ya go... using your original fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9kKXX/4/

Answer (score 0):

Only a small change is necessary.

```
$(function(){
//var input = $('form :input[type="text"]')
$('form :input[type="text"]').live('keyup',function(){   
        $('form .create-playlist-button').attr('disabled',$(this).val().length==0);
 });
 });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9kKXX/36/